# How to open URL's using telegraf JS markup inline keyboard in telegram in app browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

Code Snippet:

```
ctx.reply(
    `Hi! ${ctx.from.first_name}  \n \n Shall we start?  `,
    Markup.inlineKeyboard(
      [
  
        Markup.button.url(
          "Covid-19  IN",
          "https://www.covid19india.org/"
        ),
        Markup.button.url("WHO ", "https://covid19.who.int/"),
       

      ],
      { columns: 2 }
    )
  );
```

This is throwing a 400 Bad request URL exception.

Any help, how to open these URL's in telegram inline browser ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ctx.replyWithHTML(texts, Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                  [Markup.button.url(linktext,url)]
             ]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Markup.urlButton("NAME", "https://url.com/"),
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74663537/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).